# Link only available for my own app

Tags: java, php, android, hyperlink

I upload some data to my server with my application. I send the data to a PHP file on the server and this PHP write the data in my database. This works fine.

But currently I have the link to this PHP unsave in my Android code.

Is there a possibility to save this link or make my PHP only for my app available?

Comment: Take a look at using OAuth (http://oauth.net/) for authentication between android app and php script. It will ensure that someone doesn't sniff out a GET or POST variable with a static key in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static key could work but if the key is compromised by an app owner sniffing their own network traffic this protection will quickly break. A cryptographic system should be used instead, for example simple hashing of a secret salt with the time and date.

Both the client and the server should take the date and time to the minute in the *same* string format, concatenate it with a secret salt, and hash that. As long as the times are in synchrony, it should be fine.

You can also use a challenge-response system. The first request gets a challenge value, and all future requests include `hash($challenge.$secretkey)` which the server verifies.

More complex but worthwhile is OAuth.

Comment: where should I save the salt? Maybe the poblem is that s.o. can see my code and sees the salt....

Comment: @Billabong Inside the app, and with the apk and dex files obfuscated with a tool like DexGuard or a free alternative to same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send some secret key as GET parameter to your PHP script.

You can set it on your app and then check it in your PHP script.

Something like this:

```
script.php?key=893284932890482304
```

And in your PHP script:

```
if ($_GET['key'] = '893284932890482304')
{
   // do the rest
}
```

Another option is to set "User-Agent" in your app and then check this information in your PHP script. To be honest, I have no idea how to set "User-Agent" in Android app or iPhone app or whatever you have there, but there is probably some way to do so.

Comment: If the key is compromised by an app owner sniffing their own network traffic this protection will quickly break. A cryptographic system should be used instead,

Comment: I just gave an example of how to do that generally. It could be POST request to hide that key, or SSL can be used, whatever is better.

Comment: Neither is truly secure as POST can be intercepted and SSL can use spoofed certificates(for MITM) that the android device trusts.